# function to print all combination from number of arrays given

Tags: php

[image: the list of all combination is what i wanna print]

could you guys help me with this, i got numbers of array (up to five kinds of arrays), and i want to print all the combinations using each array elements, and it has to be unique example : array 1 elements can't combine with array 1 elements, it can only be combined with array n+1 array elements.

```
    $array1 = array('a1', 'a2');
    $array2 = array('b1', 'b2','b3');
    $array3 = array('c1', 'c2','c3');




    //combine those array into this array
    $combinationlist = array(
        array('a1', 'b1', 'c1'),
        array('a1', 'b1', 'c2')
        //and so on just like the spreadsheets
    );
```

Comment: Have you [**tried anything**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) so far?

Comment: I don't see what the spreadsheet example has to do with the bracketed example below.  Can you give a better example of a sample of your source data and your expected result?

Comment: @TheDog
  $array1 = array('a1', 'a2');
  $array2 = array('b1', 'b2','b3');
  $array3 = array('c1', 'c2','c3');




  //combine those array into this array
  $combinationlist = array(
   array('a1', 'b1', 'c1'),
   array('a1', 'b1', 'c2')
   //and so on just like the spreadsheets
  );